# How to enable pdo oci in xampp linux machine (oracle linux)

Tags: php, linux, oracle, pdo

I installed xampp on my linux system, then activated oci through below commands.

```
/opt/lampp/lampp oci8
```

Then automatically patched oci. Took instantclient path automatically

```
/opt/lampp/lib/instantclient-11.2.0.3.0
```

and activated it successfully. 
But I need pdo_oci, how to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

You should note that there're two completely different PHP extensions designed to connect to Oracle databases:

- [OCI8](http://php.net/oci8) is the extension developed by Oracle Corporation. It's
  actively maintained and it's the recommended way to interact with
  Oracle.
- [PDO_OCI](http://php.net/pdo_oci) is the PDO driver developed by the community. It was
  never finished and it's actually kind of abandoned (thus the
  EXPERIMENTAL warning displayed in the documentation).

Both contain the OCI (Oracle Call Interface) term because both make use internally of the OCI API provided by Oracle. As such, you need the Oracle Instant Client no matter what library you choose. But you then need to install the corresponding PHP packages.

In your case, you're installing OCI8 and then trying to run PDO code.

Now I'm trying to install "pdo_oci" following this: http://lacot.org/blog/2009/11/03/ubuntu-php5-oci8-and-pdo_oci-the-perfect-install.html

Comment: http://lacot.org/blog/2009/11/03/ubuntu-php5-oci8-and-pdo_oci-the-perfect-install.html